# Is it beneficial to compile Java code directly into native exe in Docker environment

Tags: java, docker, jvm

Docker is also a kind of VM then do we really need JVM to run our Java code. Instead, we can directly compile into the native executables. Docker container is going to package complete dependencies to run exe.

Please comment.

I do not want to start any comparison of Java language. Just want to understand the advantage of JVM running inside Docker container.

Comment: Docker is not a virtual machine. It is just a fancy way to run a process in your host's already running kernel.

Answer (score 0):

A Java program compiled into a "native executable" is typically just a JVM packaged with the .class files.

So the difference to installing it on top a JRE is mainly a bit less space used because not all the JRE tools are included.